# Does using Meteor with React mean that you don't have to use IronRouter or FlowRouter?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, iron-router

I've been exploring more about Meteor with React but one question that hasn't been answered going through their documentation is whether React removes the need for a router or rather if it simply removes the need to bind the collection to the Router and abstracts that essentially rendering the router to only that function; routing.

Does this make sense?

What i'm trying to figure out is if IronRouter will suffice with my Meteor+React app or if I should move to the FlowRouter paradigm if I'm taking the reactive path anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React can be used in conjunction with iron router or other routing systems provided in Meteor packages.

Personally, I have integrated [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router), a routing system built on top of React, and use that and forgo both Blaze and any router built on top of Blaze. Doing so makes it easier for me to manage my routes and components in a single React component. I have a demo repository on [Github](https://github.com/alexgaribay/meteor-react-demo) that can be a good starting point as well as [setup tutorial](http://alexgaribay.com/2015/07/06/getting-started-with-meteor-react-and-react-router/) that goes through the repo step by step if you want to go down this path.

Comment: I hadn't even heard of React-Router will check out. Thanks.

Comment: Also thanks for the demo it's clear and easy to follow.

Comment: So does this mean that you don't use Meteor for your reactive data and managing your full stack in general? Also are you using the [react-router](https://atmospherejs.com/pete/react-router) wrapper or just straight through NPM?

Comment: I still use Meteor for reactive data. The official Meteor React package has a mixin for react components for reactive data fetching. The only difference now is that I'm no longer using Blaze to present that data to the user and I use React instead. My [sample class](https://github.com/alexgaribay/meteor-react-demo/blob/master/client/Items.jsx) shows this in action. And I'm using react router through NPM. I edited my answer that links to my blog post on how to set it all up.

Comment: Just curious but does it feel natural to you putting markup in JS? I mean generally speaking that's how some things have always been done. But I have to admit that I like Blaze but feel that React is a better solution so just wanted your personal take on whether you may have found a way to still write some markup and use React or if you just use React for all UI components. I'm thinking there might be a happy medium of using both but not sure yet. All in all over time it's probably easier to use one technique and stick to it, but I always like others views on that point. Care to share? Thanks.

Comment: I personally love React. Client logic is much more visible and easier to handle since everything is in small modules. It takes a little time to get used to it so make sure to play around with React to get a feel on it. Work with it on small parts and build up to something bigger.

Comment: @Alex_Garibay, from your test repo I noticed that you were specifying a route "item" so would I just create another render function within the "Routes" component to create a route to the root?

Comment: You would create another `<Route path="anotherPath' component={SomeComponent}/>` under the parent `Routes` component. This will match the route of /anotherPath.

Comment: Hi, What do you think of using iron-router with React?  Will that have negative side effects?