# Blaze and Iron Router

Tags: meteor, react-router, meteor-blaze

I'm exploring meteor 1.3 and started with Blaze for the templates. Now I'm considering moving to React. I have a few questions.

1) Can I use Blaze and React on the same project? What would happen to modules like Account-passwords if move to React ?

2) With Blaze I was using Iron Router. If I move to react, it would be a single page app and wont need Iron Router, correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does using Meteor with React mean that you don't have to use IronRouter or FlowRouter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234783/does-using-meteor-with-react-mean-that-you-dont-have-to-use-ironrouter-or-flowr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can - [I wrote up a how to over here](https://johngibby.com/blog/Meteor_React_NPM_without_changing_your_workflow). In fact, this is my preferred way of working in meteor right now.
2. No, moving to react has nothing to do with where/how you render your components and does not force you into a SPA. There are many routing patterns available to you now, with iron-router you can server side route to a blaze template which has a helper for your react component. That's how I do it, but it's only one way. You could also switch to flow-router and use its ssr package. Or, you could switch to react router. It's all up to you, but since you're just starting I would suggest you use my approach until you get up to speed.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking. Thanks. Great blog post!

Comment: In your opinion, new that Meteor is moving to React or Blaze 2... what is the way to go for new meteor development, starting from scratch. React? Blaze? Blaze+React?

Comment: If I were starting today I'd go pure React. I don't think there will be a Blaze 2 from what I hear, but who knows. Either way, React is king right now so I'd go with that. I just happen to like Blaze and see no reason to discontinue it's use for the foreseeable future.